# returned non-zero exit status 3 python2.7 subprocess check_output

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, curl, subprocess

I have written some python code that makes a subprocess call that executes a curl command however I am getting an error `Command '['sh', '/tests/curlhttp.sh', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk', '80']' returned non-zero exit status 3`  I have also tried running that command via the terminal on my linux box and this seems to be ok.  Here is my python script

```
def RunCURL(command):
    result = []
    //I get an error when running this
    output = check_output(command.split(" "), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print output
    # loop through and create a list of lists
    for line in output.splitlines():
        if "=" in line and "time_total" not in line:
            sublist = line.split("=")[0].rstrip().lstrip()
            print sublist + " hello this is curl"
            result.append(sublist)
    return result
```

and here is my curl script I am trying to execute:

```
    #!/bin/bash
curl -w '\ncontent_type=%{content_type}\nfilename_effective=%{filename_effective}\nftp_entry_path=%{ftp_entry_path}\nhttp_code=%{http_code}\nhttp_connect=%{http_connect}\nlocal_ip=%{local_ip}\nlocal_port=%{local_port}\nnum_connects=%{num_connects}\nnum_redirects=%{num_redirects}\nredirect_url=%{redirect_url}\nremote_ip=%{remote_ip}\nremote_port=%{remote_port}\nsize_download=%{size_download}\nsize_header=%{size_header}\nsize_request=%{size_request}\nsize_upload=%{size_upload}\nspeed_download=%{speed_download}\nspeed_upload=%{speed_upload}\nssl_verify_result=%{ssl_verify_result}\ntime_appconnect=%{time_appconnect}\ntime_connect=%{time_connect}\ntime_namelookup=%{time_namelookup}\ntime_pretransfer=%{time_pretransfer}\ntime_redirect=%{time_redirect}\ntime_starttransfer=%{time_starttransfer}\ntime_total=%{time_total}\nurl_effective=%{url_effective}\n\n' -o /dev/null -s $1:$2
```

I have taken this curl script from this blog and have only changed the address field on the script to accept a url and a port number: http://blog.kenweiner.com/2014/11/http-request-timings-with-curl.html

This is what I get when running the curl script copied from the blog itself straight into the terminal

```
content_type=text/html; charset=UTF-8
filename_effective=/dev/null
ftp_entry_path=
http_code=302
http_connect=000
local_ip=10.250.8.99
local_port=60839
num_connects=1
num_redirects=0
redirect_url=https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=_7gdWOrCLrH38Af1qoKIBw
remote_ip=216.58.204.36
remote_port=443
size_download=262
size_header=258
size_request=78
size_upload=0
speed_download=3535.000
speed_upload=0.000
ssl_verify_result=0
time_appconnect=0.062
time_connect=0.013
time_namelookup=0.001
time_pretransfer=0.062
time_redirect=0.000
time_starttransfer=0.074
time_total=0.074
url_effective=https://www.google.com/
```

When I place this script into a file I get this

```
content_type=
filename_effective=/dev/null
ftp_entry_path=
http_code=000
http_connect=000
local_ip=
local_port=0
num_connects=0
num_redirects=0
redirect_url=
remote_ip=
remote_port=0
size_download=0
size_header=0
size_request=0
size_upload=0
speed_download=0.000
speed_upload=0.000
ssl_verify_result=0
time_appconnect=0.000
time_connect=0.000
time_namelookup=0.000
time_pretransfer=0.000
time_redirect=0.000
time_starttransfer=0.000
time_total=0.000
url_effective=https://www.google.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [cUrl error codes](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) it looks like 3 means that your URL is malformatted. Does it work when you run it outside of Python?

Comment: I copied and pasted the curl script from the blog and just ran that, and it worked.  however when I copy and paste it into a shell file it does not seem to give me any information back other than the labels.  I have edited my post to include the output expected against the output I get from the curl script placed in a file by called sh command